# Magento 1.9 Individual Product Info Tab For Different Manufacturers

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create an individual product info tab on the frontend product page which will include delivery info. This info will be different depending on the manufacturer of the product (attribute)

I was thinking something along the lines of an if else statement but I'm not sure this is the best way of achieving this.

Any ideas/suggestions very welcome.

Many thanks,
Mark.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: where you want to show info

Comment: Thanks @faizanbeg. I want to show the info in a product info tab (eg. next to the description tab) on each product page.

Answer (score 0):

to add a new tab to the product details you just need to call "addToParentGroup" for another block, so for example:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="xxx/manufactuer" name="product.manufacture.details" as="manufacture_details" template="xxxx.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Tab Title</title></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

another idea, which would be very similar in the way magento handel different types of products and would allow you to have full freedom when designing the tab. If you take a look at the `catalog.xml` you will find a sections like:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
...
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
...
</PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
```

as i guess that your manufacturer list is quiet fix or at least the ones with a custom layout you could try something like that.

so for example

```
<MANUFACTURER_XXX>
    <block type="xxx/manufactuer" name="product.manufacture.details" as="manufacture_details" template="xxxx.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    </block>
</MANUFACTURER_XXX>
<MANUFACTURER_YYYY>
...
</MANUFACTURER_YYYY>
```

then subscribe a new event observer for example for the event 'catalog_controller_product_view' and add one of the new created layout handler or maybe default one if non matches.

This would be a very generic approach and would give you the option to even create complex manufacturer tabs.

Hope thats a starting point for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Justus. What would you suggest I put in the template file?

Comment: iam unsure if i get it right. do you mean the "xxx.phtml" template for the manufacturer_details blog? if so take a look at "catalog/product/view/description.phtml" and "catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml" as they would use the same logic

Comment: Thanks faizanbeg. The more I look into this the more I think it is a custom xml file. The "delivery" block is as follows;

Comment: <block type='thedistance_producttabs/tab_attribute' name='product.info.tabset.tab.attribute.delivery' translate='title'> <action method='setProductAttributeCode'> <product_atttribute_code>delivery</product_atttribute_code> </action> <action method='setTitle'>

Comment: <title>Delivery</title> </action> <action method='setFallback'> <id>product-tab-default-delivery</id> <type>static_block</type> </action> <action method='setShowIfEmpty'> <show_if_empty>1</show_if_empty> </action> </block>

Answer (score 0):

`<catalog_product_view>
    <block type="manufacturer/manufacturer_info" name="manuf.description" as="manu_info" template="manufacturer/info.phtml">
      <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Title</value></action>
       </block>
    </catalog_product_view>`
 you can easy add using this

Comment: Thanks for your help faizanbeg. What would you suggest I put in the template file?

Comment: open catalog->product->view.phtml in your current them and find $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info','getChildHtml');

Comment: Thanks faizanbeg but I meant in template="manufacturer/info.phtml"

Comment: you have to mentioned the right file path in above xml template="your_path_to_file" do you know the path?

Comment: Thanks faizanbeg. The more I look into this the more I think it is a custom xml file. The "delivery" block is as follows;

Comment: <block type='thedistance_producttabs/tab_attribute'
                   name='product.info.tabset.tab.attribute.delivery'
                   translate='title'>
                <action method='setProductAttributeCode'>
                    <product_atttribute_code>delivery</product_atttribute_code>
                </action>
                <action method='setTitle'>

Comment: <title>Delivery</title>
                </action>
                <action method='setFallback'>
                    <id>product-tab-default-delivery</id>
                    <type>static_block</type>
                </action>
                <action method='setShowIfEmpty'>
                    <show_if_empty>1</show_if_empty>
                </action>
            </block>